# Unable to data from Google Finance in string format through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-finance

```javascript
function getData(){

    $.get("http://www.google.com/finance/getprices?q=.NSEI&x=NSE&i=60&p=1d&f=d, o, h, l, c, v", function(data){
        alert("Data:"+data);
});

 }   
getData();
```

The above URL gives response in string format and not in JSON format, so I can't use $.getJSON.

I am able to get the data in Java, but using JavaScript, the data is not coming and the alert is not executed.

How can I get data from external URL through `$.get` method?

Comment: Read up on same origin policy. Also, the variable should be `data`, not `Data`.

Comment: I am able to get data in jason format through other google finance URL-https://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=NSE:RELIANCE

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access data from a different domain than it is hosted on, which is in violation of the [Same-Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). In essence, this is a security measure taken to prevent cross-site scripting attacks.

Therefore, you cannot make requests to a different domain unless it supports [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). If you look in your browser console, you should see this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.google.com/finance/getprices?q=.NSEI&x=NSE&i=60&p=1d&f=d,%20o,%20h,%20l,%20c,%20v. Origin http://example.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

There are [ways around it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy), but that is most certainly the reason why you can access the data in Java and not in JavaScript.

Comment: I am able to get data in jason format through other google finance URL-finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=NSE:RELIANCE –

Comment: @user3367964 Yes, but you can't make a request to it, because it also does not support CORS.

Answer (score 0):

Try making the request from the server rather than the front end, for example, if you are doing this on a node app or a java app, create an endpoint on your server and then expose it as a rest service, then call that endpoint from the UI using `$.get()` or `xml http` request.

So, basically the server will then be fetching that data and passing it on the front-end when you call that endpoint on your server.